# setting up environment specific log4j2 with spring boot 1.4.2

Tags: xml, spring, spring-boot, yaml, log4j2

I am trying to set up log4j2 logging for a spring boot(1.4.2) application.
I want o create environment specific log4j2 files.
My setup looks like
In application.yml file

```
logging:
    config: classpath:log4j2_qa.xml
```

I have log4j2_qa.xml created. Both application.yml and loq4j2_qa.xml files are under src/main/resources. When i run the application i get the following error

> ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found. Using default configuration: logging only errors to the console.

When i rename the log4j2_qa.xml to log4j2.xml it doesn't give the error.

Answer (score 0):

`log4j2_qa.xml` is not a valid log4j-2 configuration filename that [be recognized and discoverable by log4j-2](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html).
 But `log4j2.xml` is.

Here is a snippet of the valid log4j-2 configuration filename. 
Note that the order matters:

> 1. Log4j will inspect the "log4j.configurationFile" system property and, if set, will attempt to load the configuration using the
>      ConfigurationFactory that matches the file extension.
> 2. If no system property is set the properties ConfigurationFactory will look for log4j2-test.properties in the classpath.
>
> ................
>
> 9. If a JSON file cannot be located the XML ConfigurationFactory will try
>      to locate **log4j2.xml** on the classpath.
> 10. **If no configuration file could be located the DefaultConfiguration will be used**. This will cause logging output to go to the console.

You said :

> I want to create environment specific log4j2 files

[Spring Boot profiles](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html) are designed to achieve that.
This is even their main role.
A `qa` profile makes sense.

Comment: I do have profiles in my application. Could you give me an example of how to configure the logging level in the profiles. Application.properties file has the profile settings.